Why are my gears hard to shift when my car is hot
When my car is cold it’s easy to shift and the clutch bite point is high but when it warms up its bite point is at the floor and it’s hard to down shift and up shift.
Ford Fiesta.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Dare I say? You need a clutch service.

If the point at which the clutch is engaging is changing as you drive, I believe the issue is going to be the clutch master cylinder or slave cylinder.  It seems like air is getting into the system somewhere and not allowing the slave cylinder to fully extend as normal.
It is normal for shifting to be difficult when you cannot fully release the clutch.  The synchronizers have to do more work to engage the gears.

The problem could be with your clutch hose. When it heats up, it becomes more pliable and may expand when pressure is applied, instead of delivering that pressure to the slave cylinder.
I had this exact issue, and the culprit was the flexible part of the clutch line that ran beside the engine block. Replaced that bit with a new, braided stainless hose and the problem went away. A new OEM hose might have worked just as well, but the upgraded one was cheap enough that I didn't consider it.
